# What does the degree symbol in $K_n \subset K_{n+1}^{\circ}$ mean?

Tags: notation

What does the degree symbol in "Let $(K_n)$ be a sequence of compact subsets such that $K_n \subset K_{n+1}^{\circ}$ mean?

Comment: Almost certainly, "interior".

Comment: The [interior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) of the set.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You or David should post this as an answer so that the asker can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, it almost certainly means the [interior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29#Interior_operator) of the set.